# Spring Integration JMS Gateway without reply listener

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jms, spring-integration

I'm having a challenge with Spring Integration with the following case.

Same application (Spring Integration) is running on several servers, 
For JMS (outbound) I am using the jms:outbound-channel-adapter, but checking the outbound gateway i notice that there has the parameters that is used to tune the JMS Queue (explicit-qos-enabled, time-to-live and so on), but the problem is the "reply-listener", since the application is running on several servers connected to other servers (other gateways), the reply message can be processed by other server that is not the server that sent the JMS message.

My doubt is how to configure the "outbound-gateway" without any "reply-listener", which means no "reply-listener" configured (neither the precreated since will create a thread that maybe never receive the reply and will hold a thread (listener thread) without any reason).

Reading the documentation I understood that this is not possible. 
Is it true? like there are no way to use the outbound gateway without the "reply-listener"?

Answer (score 0):

Let me just quote the `JmsOutboundGateway` source code a bit:

```
if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
    logger.warn("The gateway cannot use a reply listener container with a specified destination(Name/Expression) " +
                "without a 'correlation-key'; " +
                "a container will NOT be used; " +
                "to avoid this problem, set the 'correlation-key' attribute; " +
                "some consumers, including the Spring Integration <jms:inbound-gateway/>, " +
                "support the use of the value 'JMSCorrelationID' " +
                "for this purpose. Alternatively, do not specify a reply destination " +
                "and a temporary queue will be used for replies.");
    }
```

And a bit later in the `handleRequestMessage`:

```
if (this.replyContainer == null) {
    jmsReply = this.sendAndReceiveWithoutContainer(requestMessage);
}
```

So, you can use `<int-jms:outbound-gateway>` without `reply-listener`.
Something like this:

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway request-destination="requestQueueA" 
                              reply-destination="replyQueueB" 
                              connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
```

Comment: So setting the reply destination, the "reply-listener" will not be created? My doubt regards the temporary queue neither the reply-listener shall be created. and Setting ther reply-destination will add it to the JMS header, if i have like 300 queues with another 300 reply queues the configuration is quite verbose. (And in fact the JMS config is something like that). Regards.

Comment: Yes, it relies on the `consumerSession.createConsumer(replyTo, messageSelector);`

Comment: I will test and check what happens. Tks.

Comment: Even when using the reply listener; each gateway will only see it's own replies - the gateway uses a message selector to only consume replies to requests that it initiated.