# Spring Integration Gateway Without Reply in DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

My question is very similar to this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503621/spring-integration-jms-gateway-without-reply-listener) in that I want to send to JMS and then carry on with my integration flow.

The response is totally asynchronous and is therefore handled on a separate `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter`. So, I basically want to "fire and forget".

My code is this (Spring 5.3.14);

```
.enrichHeaders(
    h -> h.headerFunction("JMSCorrelationID", m -> m.getHeaders().get(MessageHeaders.ID))
)
.handle(
   Jms
      .outboundGateway(connectionFactory)
      .requestDestination(queueName)
   )
.handle(p -> System.err.println("Do something else with ... " + p))
.get();
```

And I get this;

`org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 5000ms,`

The referenced answer to me implies that I need to listen to a dummy queue, which I don't want to have to do. So what do I need to fix in my code above?

**Edit; final code using the solution below** tested with/without "queue PUT inhibit" in order cause an exception.

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
  .subscribe(f -> f.handle(
    Jms
      .outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
      .destination(queueName)
  ))
  .subscribe(f -> f.handle(
    p -> System.err.println("Do something else with ... " + p)
  ))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Jms.outboundChannelAdapter()` instead. And together with that next `handle()` wrap them into a `publishSubscribeChannel()` as two subscribers sub-flows. This way they are going to be called one after other, but in parallel and their individual flows.

Comment: Thank for your response. In my example code, the implication was that if the `JMS.OutboundGateway` were to fail (e.g. JMS Exception), then processing would jump to the "errorChannel" and not reach the `handle()`. However, if were to run in  parallel via `publishSubscibeChannel()` , how could I prevent the `handle()` from running when a JMSException occurred? I would guess that the `handle()` could listen to the same channel defined in `errorChannel()` of the `outboundChannelAdapter()`. However we would be in a race-condition, as the error would be delayed by "timeout" ms.

Comment: Same with `publishSubscibeChannel()`. It has `ignoreFailures` as `false` by default. So, if the current subscriber fails, the next one is not going to be called. But instead an exception is going to be thrown upstream when your `errorChannel` may take actions. Just don't use an `Executor` for that `publishSubscibeChannel()` and the `handle()` sub-flow is going to be called only after JMS one finishes its job properly. If error, no the next subscriber.

Comment: Ah I see. So if i don’t use an executor, the subscribes run sequentially and not in parallel as I had imagined. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That's the word: `sequentially`. Thank you for reminder!